# Add many for commands

Tags: javascript

Hey can smeone please help me with this
well i want to add many variables and get them to check the arrays but it just doesnt work.
I wanted it to check all the text in the textbox and if it is the same as the arrays then it would provide an alert.
here is my code

```
function setValue(){
myVariable= document.forms["myform"]["gname"].value;
myVariable1= document.forms["myform"]["graphic"].value;
myVariable2= document.forms["myform"]["gpc"].value;
myVariable3= document.forms["myform"]["procesor"].value;
myVariable4= document.forms["myform"]["ram"].value;
myVariable5= document.forms["myform"]["os"].value;
var graphic = ["radeon hd", "nvidia"];
var gname = ["prince of persia", "grand theft auto"];
var gpc = ["radeon hd 121", "nvidia 121"];
var procesor = ["intel i7", "intel i5", "intel i3"];
var os = ["Windows 7", "Windows 8", "Windows xp"];
var ram = ["4 Gb", "8 Gb", "12 Gb"];
    var canRun = false;

for(i=0;i<ram.length;i++)
(i=0;i<gpc.length;i++)
(i=0;i<os.length;i++)
(i=0;i<procesor.length;i++)
(i=0;i<gname.length;i++)
(i=0;i<graphic.length;i++)

    {
        if (myVariable5 === os[i] && myVariable4 === ram[i] && myVariable3 === procesor[i] && myVariable2 === gpc[i] && myVariable1 === graphic[i] && myVariable === gname[i]) 
        {   
            canRun = true;  
        }
    }

    if (canRun)
    {   
        alert("yes this game can run");
    }
    else 
    {       
        alert("No, This game cannot run");
    }
};
```

Comment: "doesnt work" isn't perfectly clear. Does it give the opposite alert you expected? Does nothing happen at all? Is there an error in the browser's debugging console? (Try pressing F12 in the browser, then perhaps refreshing, to get more details)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just smush `for` loops together like that. You need a separate loop for each array, or, more simply, use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) instead.

Comment: No. It's a very simple task. If you want to be any kind of a programmer, you need to know how to do these kinds of extremely basic things yourself.

Comment: ok thank you soo much for the answer which did not help me directly but did help when i used the index of  code and fyi it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You may to run one loop at a time, like this:

```
var ok_count = 0;
for(i=0;i<ram.length;i++) {
    (myVariable4 === ram[i]) {
         ok_count++;
         break;
    }
}
for (i=0;i<gpc.length;i++) {
    (myVariable2 === gpc[i]) {
         ok_count++;
         break;
    }
}
if (ok_count == 2) { 
       // MATCH :-D
}
else {
       // NO MATCH :-(
}
```

Comment: You can just make for loops for the other checks also. `ok_count == 2` checks how many for loops match. Replace `2` with the number of loops.

Comment: @Atle It's better to use `indexOf` instead of loops

Comment: Yes, it does kindof the same only behind the scenes.

Comment: @Atle Yeah, but `indexOf` uses a browser native loop, which is much faster than a JS loop.

Comment: However, I reckon it's good to show new users ways of solving more low-level programming problems without using built-in functions. In this case you may use `indexOf`, but in another case (or language) you may have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
function setValue(){
    var canRun = true,
        accepted = {
            graphic: ["radeon hd", "nvidia"],
            gname: ["prince of persia", "grand theft auto"],
            gpc: ["radeon hd 121", "nvidia 121"],
            procesor: ["intel i7", "intel i5", "intel i3"],
            os: ["Windows 7", "Windows 8", "Windows xp"],
            ram: ["4 Gb", "8 Gb", "12 Gb"]
        };
    for(var i in accepted){
        // If you have modified `Object.prototype`, you should also check
        // `accepted.hasOwnProperty(i)`
        if(accepted[i].indexOf(document.forms['myform'][i].value) === -1) {
            canRun = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(canRun ? "yes this game can run" : "No, This game cannot run");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to see if the values submitted are within a range of valid values.  Just use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
if (graphic.indexOf(myVariable1) >= 0 && ram.indexOf(myVariable2) && ...) {
    canRun = true;
}
```

The code above says: if the `graphic` array contains the value submitted from the form, mark it as valid (and checks the other fields too).

I like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) a lot, you can use that as well.

```
if (_.contains(graphic, myVariable1) && _.contains(ram, myVariable2) && ...) {
```

Comment: thank you @Zachary Yates the first part of the comment really helped me but the second part i prefer using my var array and myVariables but thank you very much.